# How can i make the 'poo' appear in a certain place when the screen is touched?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am making a game in sprite kit, for the iphone and i am a noob haha. Anyway, this is the code i have so far but instead of the poo appearing where i touch i want it to appear in a place of my choice.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 /* Called when a touch begins */

for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    SKSpriteNode *poo = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"poo"];

    poo.position = location;

    poo.zPosition = 5;

    [poo setScale:0.2f];


    //next line adds gravity to the poo.
    poo.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:poo.size.width/2];

    [self addChild:poo];
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried to set the position to a different location? http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a `CGPoint` with a desired location and set it as a position:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    CGPoint yourLocationOfChoice = CGPointMake(200.0f, 200.0f);

    SKSpriteNode *poo = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"poo"];

    poo.position = yourLocationOfChoice;

    ...
}
```

Comment: To explicitly tell the compiler that you are entering a float number.